# How do I only get images using the praw module

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I made a discord bot to get stuffs from a subreddit and send it, now the bot includes images and videos, how do I configure it so that it only sends the image (videos take time you see... and it just sends a title of the posts)

```
 if message.content.startswith('sub'):
     subreddit = reddit.subreddit("randomsub")

     all_subs = []
     top = subreddit.hot(limit = 90)
     for submission in top:
         all_subs.append(submission)
     random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
     name = random_sub.title
     url = random_sub.url
     em = discord.Embed(title = name)
     em.set_image(url = url)
     await message.channel.send(embed = em)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if random_sub.is_reddit_media_domain and not random_sub.is_video:
    # only send title
```

which will check that the item is hosted on reddit (not an outside source) and that it is not a video. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520751/how-do-i-check-if-a-reddit-post-contains-only-an-image-and-nothing-else/54561694#54561694)

If you were trying to filter videos on other websites such as imgur or gfycat those would be improperly filtered. Therefore you would need to check the URL for a file ending to not contain '.mp4' or other video file types.