# How do i only scrape image reddit posts using praw?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, reddit, praw

with my code below I also find gifs, but I only want to find image posts.
I could filter posturl_list for .gif but I dont know how to delete the title in posttitle_list that is related to the gif.

```
posturl_list = []
posttitle_list = []

top_post = reddit.subreddit('memes').top("day", limit=12)
for post in top_post:
    posturl = post.url
    posttitle = post.title
    posturl_list.append(posturl)
    posttitle_list.append(posttitle)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328139/how-do-i-only-get-images-using-the-praw-module does this help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with it you can download [RedDownloader](https://pypi.org/project/RedDownloader/)

and then simply do

```
from RedDownloader import RedDownloader
RedDownloader.DownloadImagesBySubreddit("subreddit name here" , 10) #10 is number of posts to download
```

Comment: I dont want to download the images, only add them to the list